# Position element in middle of screen using CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

After my website was completed, everyday I am trying to modify things that would make it more responsive. It's made in Muse so don't expect much of "responsiveness".

I have an element with this class:

```
#labelstrong
 {
    z-index: 17;
    width: 633px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: justify;
    position: fixed;
    top: 1542px;
    left: 164px;
 }
```

Normally, the element is in the middle of the screen. But when I zoom out, the element maintains the same distance to the top of the screen (because of the top attribute of course). How can I define its position in a way that even if I zoom in or out it will still be in the middle of the screen.

UPDATE: 
The problem is (and I forgot to mention it) that the position must be fixed as there is an horizontal scrolling feature for all elements ( they come from the right of the screen) and so they have to be on a fixed position.

UPDATE 2: Here is a live example. Imagine that the class is applied on each TAG (not the menu of course).

http://2323029s8s8s8.businesscatalyst.com/index.html

Comment: Place the label with fixed position and greater zindex outside the horisontally scrollable element.

Comment: @Ricky the issues is with the big tags that slide along as you scroll?

Comment: Yes. As you can see in the link .. While zooming out the remain in a fixed position near to the top. I wan to keep the position:fixed but keep them in the middle. :(

Comment: If anyone wants I can export this website in html. I don't expect you to write the code. No way . Just to see how is going to be achieved as muse has a bad markup language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add for those big tags the following css:

```
.fixed-big-tag{
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Also as a counter measure, make sure the `<body>` and the `<html>` have 100% heights

Another idea would be to use the `!important` rule for the `top property` to overwrite what Muse outputs.(or any rule that needs to be overwritten)

If it works, you could probably add a new class on all these tags that need to be centered and overwrite it via css

Check it out, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks I tried it but it didn't work. Muse defines 100% in a different way. 
CSS:  body
{
 position: relative;
 min-width: 960px;
 padding-top: 36px;
 padding-bottom: 36px;
}

Comment: #page
{
 z-index: 1;
 width: 960px;
 min-height: 4940px;
 background-image: none;
 border-style: none;
 border-color: transparent;
 background-color: transparent;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

Comment: Muse.Utils.fullPage('#page');/* 100% height page */

Comment: @Ricky cant you define some sort of a class to set on all those tags? and if so, you could overwrite what it outputs, by including it in a css or via inline styling?

Comment: like setting inside that class: top: 50% !important

Comment: You mean assign a new class on these tags and add the !important ?

Comment: About editing the css file. Of course this is all about. I've exported my website in HTML and I am trying to modify it. That class as seen in the post is defined in MUSE css exported file.

Comment: I think you're the winner here. SOlution was : delete the old class. Add a new one. Replace all instances of the old one with the new in the html code. and add !important to top and transform. Please provide this as a new anwer so I can "award" you as a winner. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

See this resource for techniques to centering elements using CSS: [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

If you create a relatively-positioned parent container element, you can center your child element easily:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

#labelstrong {
  z-index: 17;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: justify;
  position: absolute;

  width: 634px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -317px;
}
```

Note that the `margin` offsets are half of the width and height.

Comment: Thanks I've already seen this. The problem is (and I forgot to mention it) that the position must be fixed as there is an horizontal scrolling feature for all elements ( they come from the right of the screen) and so they have to be on a fixed position. Is there any way with fixed position?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with an example of your layout?

Comment: Well it's impossible to do this on a Jsfiddle. I can create a temp site on adobe business catalyst and post it here. It won't take time. What you think?

Comment: If the other posted answers didn't work for you either, then yes go for it.

Comment: Check the link please (see the post)

Answer (score 0):

Try using percentages instead of pixels, like:

```
top: 10%;
```

If you want to horizontally center, try setting the margin to auto:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Your code would look like this:

```
#labelstrong {
    z-index: 17;
     width: 633px;
     background-color: transparent;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     text-align: justify;
     position: relative;
     top: 10%;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/5a6fyb21/

Comment: No. I tried this. it doesn't work. position must be fixed (we can't change this).  Thanks though

Comment: Why don't you use float instead? All items would be next to each other. But I can't imagine if you don't give us an example of your code.

Comment: @Ricky http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861247/center-aligning-a-fixed-position-div

Comment: Check the link please (see the post)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would be your best bet.

I would just set your class to a fixed position then try using the following.

```
$(window).resize(function() {    
var middle = $(window).height();
$('.middle').css('top', hello / 2);
});
```

The resize function is used so that it will remain in position if the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

Centered label over horisontally scrollable content:

http://jsfiddle.net/cqztf9kc/

```
.fixed {
    margin: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content {
    x-overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```