# Can't center my website even with div wrapper

Tags: css, html, center

I can't seem to get the website I'm building to center.

I put the website online for you to find the problem:

http://www.piccadilly.london/gourmetdinner-alpha.html and http://www.piccadilly.london/gourmet-alpha.css

Below is my wrapper css, if this is helpful:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1270px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Waiting for any answers to solve this - thanks in advance.

Comment: Because everything inside is has un-static positioning. So the size of your wrapper div is virtually nothing. Because of this, it can't be treated as a block element.

Comment: If you put position: relative on your #wrapper you will center all but your header. You have a fixed with header that will stay left-aligned unless you adjust the width to be a percentage of the containing element. The post below has some explanation.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861247/center-aligning-a-fixed-position-div

Comment: A lot of `absolute` elements. Also, if you don't use media query for responsive design then never aim at width more than 960px and assume width of scroll bars. That kind of design is ___terribad___. Hope you're not charging anyone for it.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your html elements have

```
position: absolute;
```

This is almost never a good idea.

Check this answer for some more details: [center aligning a fixed position div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861247/center-aligning-a-fixed-position-div)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the child elements relative to the container; add the following to your wrapper.

```
position:relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `position: relative` will do the trick for now, but using absolute positioning is not the best way to go.

I would recommend trying something like Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/) which takes care of element positioning with it's Grid system letting you create fixed or responsive layouts fairly easily.

Good luck learning!

Answer (score 0):

Mikael, try this

I will explain a basic structure for doing this.

```
<header>All your header content should come here</header>
<div id="wrapper">
Container part should come here
</div>
<footer>All your footer content should come here</footer>
```

you can use the same wrapper css (also for header and footer, with position fixed), but remember when writing inner class css's, you should use `poisition:relative, or float` element. Position absolute is not nice for all time. you will get the idea of positioning and floating from `W3schools`

Comment: Also please try to make the wrapper width as standard pixels, 1270px is not a standard width.