# stretch div over whole page in html/css

Tags: html, css

I have a link and i want it to always be at the bottom of the page. I tryed display: flex and align-items: flex-end but the problem is the div isn't going till the bottom of the page. I could just do margin-top: 375px but I want that it is at the bottom at a phone and a computer can someone help?

Comment: Can edit the question and add the code that you have tried so far. Refer this link for understanding [how to ask a question ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you put the code you have so far into your question. Any answer without seeing your HTML structure will just be a guess.

Comment: You can try `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0px`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

Like others said, `bottom: 0` and `position: fixed` is what you need.

`width: 100%` will stretch the `div` across the page.

When you add `fixed` to an element, it then becomes independent of all other elements, which makes it tricky to position. I added `left: 50%;` and `transform: translate (-50%, 0);` it helps center the element to the page.

Source: ([Center aligning a fixed position div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861247/center-aligning-a-fixed-position-div))

```css
div.bottom-nav {
  background-color: #232323;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-nav"><a href=#>Click me</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding this to the element you want to stick to the bottom.

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```